# Laravel query not returns all values

Tags: php, laravel

I'm trying to make simple forum on laravel. I have two tables:
`categories`:

[image]

`forums`:

[image]

I run query:

```
$categories = DB::table('forums')
        ->join('categories', 'forums.fid', '=', 'categories.cid')
        ->select('categories.*', 'forums.*')
        ->get();
```

I receive only two results:

```
[{"cid" :1,
  "name": "First forum",
  "fid": 1,
  "seo_name": "first-forum",
  "category_id": 1
 },
 {"cid": 2,
  "name": "Another forum",
  "fid": 2,
  "seo_name": "another-forum",
  "category_id": 2
 }]
```

Why only 1 result for category_id 1? I have two forums in that category. Thanks in advance and sorry for my bad English.

Comment: You should have spent the time you wasted here on creating this question on debugging. Try to learn debugging on your own. That is the most important thing for a programmer. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need:

```
->join('categories', 'forums.category_id', '=', 'categories.cid')
```

Answer (score 1):

Update query to:

```
$categories = DB::table('forums')
        ->join('categories', 'forums.category_id', '=', 'categories.cid')
        ->select('categories.*', 'forums.*')
        ->get();
```